# advice about next step after desinging a star schema

Tags: sql, excel, data-warehouse

I have designed a star schema based on an online retail shop .

From my research the next step is to start inserting data into an excel sheet .After this is done I have to use some sort of software(Tableu ,qlikview ,etc) to generate my queries and then display them in charts,bars 
and other ways .

Can you please tell me if this is the right approach ,am I missing something else and any advice when it comes to creating data warehouses ?Thank you .

This is my star schema :
[image]

Comment: Don't use Excel as any kind of data warehouse, database, or back end for anything ever

Comment: What should I use then instead ?I'm just using Excel to insert data and then import it into a different software

Comment: If you have implemented your schema in some kind of database or data warehouse there should be no need to export to Excel. Your visualization tools (Tableau, etc...) should be able to access it directly.  You just need to set up your database connection and query

Comment: If you have so few data that is possible to input them manually, you most probably don't need a DW. Just use excel or access with pivot table (excel) or crosstab query (access). Keep it simple.